# Angular Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: record.factory is not a function when i install @auth0/angular-jwt

Tags: angular

I found other people with a similar problem to mine, but they mostly had problems with angular versions that were not aligned.
I'm also using a much newer version of Angular, v13 ad they were using Angular v11 and below

In my case everything works until I try to use the jwt decoder from @auth0/angular-jwt

This is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "e-shop-fe",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~13.3.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^13.3.9",
    "@angular/common": "~13.3.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~13.3.0",
    "@angular/core": "~13.3.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~13.3.0",
    "@angular/material": "^13.3.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~13.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~13.3.0",
    "@angular/router": "~13.3.0",
    "@auth0/angular-jwt": "^5.0.2",
    "rxjs": "~7.5.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~13.3.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~13.3.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~13.3.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.10.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
    "typescript": "~4.6.2"
  }
}
```

this is my jwtService, VSCode doesn't find any issue with this code but it makes my component crash

```
import { JwtHelperService } from "@auth0/angular-jwt";
import { Injectable, NgModule } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
@NgModule()
export class JWTService {

  constructor(private helper :JwtHelperService ) { }

  decodeToken(token:string) {

    const decodedToken = this.helper.decodeToken(token);
    return decodedToken;
  }

  public getTokenExpiration(token : string){

    const expirationDate = this.helper.getTokenExpirationDate(token);
    return expirationDate;
  }

  public isTokenExpired(token : string){

    const isExpired = this.helper.isTokenExpired(token);
    return isExpired;
  }
}
```

I know for sure the problem is the JwtHelperService, because if i remove it, the component will run properly and it can use methods from the same JWTService class

I tried with different versions of @auth0/angular-jwt,nothing changed

Someone knows what i'm doing wrong, or maybe another lybrary that i can try to use?